# How to get all numbers between a range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table as below

```
Id     RFrom      RTo
....  .......    .....
1       10         14
1       22         25
2       100        102
2       176        180
```

I want to get all numbers between each RFrom and RTo for each Id. My expected result is as follows

```
Id     NUMS
....  ......
1       10
1       11
1       12
1       13
1       14
1       22
1       23
1       24
1       25
2       100
2       101
2       102
2       176
2       177
2       178
2       179
2       180
```

Do I have to use cursor to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your sample table

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM
(
    SELECT 1 ID, 10 RFROM, 14 RTO
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,       22,         25
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,       100,        102
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,       176,        180
)TAB
```

You need to use recursion for each Id to get the result

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT ID,RFROM RFROM1,RTO RTO1 
   FROM #TEMP  
   UNION ALL
   SELECT T.ID,RFROM1+1,RTO1 
   FROM #TEMP T
   JOIN CTE ON CTE.ID = T.ID
   WHERE RFROM1 < RTO1
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID,RFROM1 NUMS 
FROM CTE
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2680/2)**

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a `numbers` table with a `join` -- recursion can be time consuming.

There are several options to create a numbers table (I'd recommend creating a permanent one), but here's a temp one created with a common-table-expression:

```
with numberstable as (
  select top 10000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as number
  from master..spt_values t1 
      cross join master..spt_values t2
  )
select yt.id,
  nt.number
from yourtable yt
  join numberstable nt on nt.number between yt.rfrom and yt.rto
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c2b3/5)

Comment: Hi sgeddes. Your answer is good and easy one but not work when there exist negative values :( Anyway. Thank you :)

Comment: @ShilpaPraneesh -- no worries, glad we helped.  The point to this solution is not the method used to create the `numbers` table -- but rather the speed benefits of using a `join` than using a `recursive query`.  Nonetheless, glad you got it working!

Comment: Yes. It is works perfect for +ve value. Thank you. I am happy for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `tally table` using `stacked CTE` which will have better performance when compared to `recursive CTE`

```
declare @min int
select @min= min(RFrom) from yourtable
;WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2) -- 10*100
SELECT b.id,
       a.n
FROM   yourtable b
       JOIN (SELECT n = Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY n)+ @min-1
             FROM   e3)a
         ON a.n BETWEEN b.RFrom AND b.RTo
ORDER  BY n;
```

Check [***here***](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) for info

Comment: This is pretty much the same as my posted solution -- just a different approach to creating the `numbers` table.  The main point of both solutions -- use `join` with `between`...

Comment: @sgeddes - Your solution is not going to work if master database cannot be accessed in production. so avoid using master database tables

Comment: Hi NoDisplayName. Not work when there exist negative values :( Anyway. Thank you :)

Comment: @NoDisplayName -- You're missing the point -- the `numbers` table is irrelevant -- it's the performance increase of the `join` over the recursive cte.  There are dozens of ways to creating a `numbers` table...

Comment: @sgeddes - yeah i already mentioned that in my answer and with a good link for detailed comparison :)

Comment: @ShilpaPraneesh - Updated to handle `negative` values